# An answer to an already closed question was flagged. How should I proceed?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

An author was flagged after answering his own question. The question was already closed as "too broad".

Answer in the LQ queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20497865

To be honest, I'm not sure what to do here. It seems like the author is providing an answer to the question, while simultaneously asking the community if the answer is correct.

I wanted to recommend for deletion as "this should be an edit to the question". However the only options available were "no comment needed" and "this is a link-only answer". Neither apply.

I am aware that I should have just skipped. It was my mistake to choose "looks OK". However I'd like the community feedback for future cases.

Answer (score 4):

> To be honest, I'm not sure what to do here.

## Skip it if you're not sure.

But since that's not the answer you came to Meta for, let's take a slightly deeper dive.

You're looking at the quality of the *answer*, not the question.  From there, a simple heuristic:

- Does the answer look like it could reasonably answer the question?
- Is it another question or a comment?
- Could editing the answer fix any grievances you may hold with it?

So long as you don't think it's actually low quality (e.g. it's another question or comment, it's not an answer, it's incoherent, etc), then it's probably fine.

But seriously, you should skip if you're ever unsure.