# Do dangling answers to a question, gone due to moderation, need deletion?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, deleted-questions

This is in the *[Low quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review)* review queue:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32820557

The question itself is no longer available.

So I clicked "Recommended deletion". None of the reasons seems to apply.
Should I just skip it as a related post for a similar situation  [An answer to an already closed question was flagged. How should I proceed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372026/an-answer-to-an-already-closed-question-was-flagged-how-should-i-proceed) suggests?

Comment: It's spam... But skipping is always a safe choice when unsure

Comment: I got "This is an audit" error message when [trying to comment on that review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tIQW.png).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan The [question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28585800/revisions) but there's a bug that's still not fixed apparently where some [deleted posts are visible even after deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400332/6083675) (as in, you can see it even without an account and it probably shows up in search too).

Comment: @Laurel Thanks.  I was unaware of that bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This is a bug

[Answers to deleted questions should not be chosen as audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194128/323179) for this very reason. However, something went wrong in [deleting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28585800/revisions), so it's still completely visible: You can see it without logging in. You can [find it in search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=I%27m+triying+to+anonymize+dcm). And, yes, its deleted answers can be chosen as audits.

This bug has been reported before with minor differences. It may or may not be fixed by [recent changes to handle improper Roomba deletions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420161/6083675) — they [rebuilt the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420582/6083675) today (and the question is now deleted properly, though I can't see if these events were related).

### What you should have done

If you see a question that was deleted according to the timeline but is still completely visible, you should flag it for moderator attention, explain this, and ask for it to be properly deleted.

As for the queue, "Looks OK" is never the correct option for spam. If you see spam, you should see if you can flag it as such, which in the Low Quality Queue means opening up the post in a new tab. If you don't see the post (or you have 10k and see it's deleted), it's probably an audit, which can be passed by deleting the answer in the queue (with any comment option — I choose no comment).

I got an [audit just like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32128399) (spam answer to a question that was improperly deleted) and I passed the audit that way. Additionally, mod re-deletion (done in response to my flag) prevents the question from being visible or the bugged audit from happening again.