# What's the issue with this answer?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-answers

I got dinged in the Low Quality Answer queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77731650/367865 [[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsq9.png)]

The queue said, "This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful."

The delete reason said, "It was flagged as spam or offensive content [...]"

This looks like an honest attempt at an answer with none of the issues listed above. I've seen many, many answers much worse than this that reviewers are still expected to OK.

Note: It's a self-answer, it's on topic, and the question wasn't deleted (so it seems it's not spam).

Comment: Looking at SmokeDetector records, it looks like the user was promoting their website across multiple seemingly-legitimate answers. The same website is linked in their bio.

Comment: Other reason to flag as low quality answer is that the [`@sentry/tracing`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/tracing) package has been officially deprecated and should not be recommended.

Comment: "dinged" meaning what? "The queue said"? I guess you failed an audit? Please just take the time to write clearly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was flagged as spam. The moderator who handled the flag nuked the answer as spam and deleted/destroyed the user, as it's clearly undisclosed affiliation and the answer and spam seed question are clearly intended to promote the company and linked blog post, which was posted a couple of days prior to the Q&A. The fact that the answer contained undisclosed affiliation is no longer as easily determined, now that the user is deleted and their username isn't available on the post. The username, which was their real name, could be Googled. The results indicate that the person works for the company to which they linked.

The Q&A is part of a group of posts promoting that company's blog, which were posted in November and December of 2023 by multiple accounts which can be traced to employees of that company. In other words, the question and answer are part of a low-level spam campaign by that company.

For some reason, the automatic deletion of the question by the Community user upon the deletion/destruction of the user was recorded in the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77731611/timeline), but failed to actually delete the question. I've corrected that.

Comment: That the question wasn't actually deleted was likely due to [SQL timeouts happening at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392335/377214).

Comment: Since the question was supposed to be deleted, the answer shouldn't have been eligible to be an audit. See also [another similar example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420581/6083675) where an answer audit was created on a half-deleted question.

Comment: Even the software makes mistakes that contribute to the lack of success the audit system has apparently. Just another reason to treat it like it is an annoying cousin. Smile at it when it visits, and then inwardly pray it won't be back for another year.

Comment: weird deletion bug aside, these particular cases where the user is destroyed and the **username** is no longer available to regular users, and the username is how you're supposed to figure out it's undisclosed affiliation are tricky audits. add that to the fact that it was part of a time-windowed pattern of activity that you'd only realize if you were there and looking for it.